# Powershell error "Cannot open SQLServerReportingServices service on computer '.'."

Tags: powershell, reporting-services, service

I am unfamiliar with PowerShell, and I'm trying to adapt the PowerShell script found on [this blog post](https://pawlowski.cz/2011/07/31/solving-issue-long-starting-report-ssrs-2008/) so that I can control when SSRS restarts.

The script opens with these lines, using the name of the SSRS service according to the service properties:

```
Stop-Service "SQLServerReportingServices"
Start-Service "SQLServerReportingServices"
```

I run the script by navigating to the directory where the script is stored in PowerShell, and entering '.\MyPSScript.ps1'. However, I get the error

`Cannot open SQLServerReportingServices service on computer '.'.`

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

In case it helps, here's the full error I get back from PowerShell, covering both the Stop-Service and Start-Service commands:

```
Stop-Service : Service 'SQL Server Reporting Services (SQLServerReportingServices)' cannot be stopped
following error: Cannot open SQLServerReportingServices service on computer '.'.
At C:\SSRS_Restart.ps1:1 char:1
+ Stop-Service "SQLServerReportingServices"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController)
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStopService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopServiceCommand

Start-Service : Service 'SQL Server Reporting Services (SQLServerReportingServices)' cannot be started
following error: Cannot open SQLServerReportingServices service on computer '.'.
At C:\SSRS_Restart.ps1:2 char:1
+ Start-Service "SQLServerReportingServices"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [
   ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

Comment: The Report Server in the Start Button contains a log file.  The log file will give more details on what caused the error.  Did you set the default credentials?  See following : https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4738/powershell-commands-for-sql-server-reporting-services/  Check which command work.

Comment: I went to the Event Viewer, and checked the Windows PowerShell logs for the date and time when I tried my script. Unfortunately, I see no entries pertaining to my script. Nothing in the various Windows logs, either.
It's *possible* that I need to run PS as an Administrator - I didn't before - so I will test that at my next opportunity.

Comment: I said to check the Report Server Log File which is in the Start Button on the Server where the shortcut to the Report Server is located.

Comment: Sorry, but there is no log file linked directly in the Start Menu on the report server. All I have is the link to the Report Server Config Manager. So I went to the SSRS logs at "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles", and while I see the log from the SSRS Service, nothing in it  mentions my attempt to stop the service via PowerShell. Looks like my script didn't get that far?

Comment: What is name of server in the configuration file?  Use the name in the PS script.  Right now it is not finding the default name.  Try registering the server : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/connect-to-a-report-server-in-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16#to-register-a-report-server